# Install Centos 5 repo on Centos 7

Tags: centos, centos7, centos5

I need to install a cntos 5 repo to download dhclient for el5 on an centos 7 machine to transfer dhclient rpms on centos 5 machine. It is possible ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible ? May be ? Copy the file CentOS-5.11.repo to /etc/yum.repos.d/ https://www.dropbox.com/s/jxs1xgrvf2l3os7/CentOS-5.11.repo?dl=0 ... **dhclient** http://vault.centos.org/5.11/os/x86_64/CentOS/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is it supported.Copy repo list from Centos 5 and add it to `/etc/yum.repos.d/`. Then run

```
yum repolist
```